# How to parse the this text and build an object

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, .net-4.0, string-matching

I am getting data from a third party application that looks like this:

```
Customer Name = Cust1.xml
    <NAME>/Mark</NAME>
    <TYPE>Type 1</TYPE>
    <ADDRESS>Some Address</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>Some City</VIRTHOSTNM>
    <ZIP>11111</ZIP>

Junction Name = Cust2.xml
    <NAME>/Robert</NAME>
    <TYPE>Type 2</TYPE>
    <ADDRESS>Address 1</ADDRESS>
    <ADDRESS>Address 2</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>City For Address 1</CITY>
    <CITY>City For Address 2</CITY>
    <ZIP>Zip For City 1/ZIP>
    <ZIP>ZIP For City 2</ZIP>
```

There can be `multiple nodes` with `Address, City and Zip`. `First City and ZIP Nodes belong to the first Address and second to the second one` and so on.

This is what i have done so far:

```
string filePath = @"C:\SomeData.txt";

var data = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

string[] customers = data.Split(new[] { "Customer Name = " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This gives me array of 2 strings.

But i am having hard time trying to loop thru and figure out how do i associate the Address City and Zip in the correct order for the data like `Cust2`.

Comment: Have you looked at using XDocument or XmlDocument?

Comment: thats what i am working on as doing this with text manipulation is not going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, if I'm understanding your problem correctly. Notice that I added a root node. Even if your document does not have this when you read it in, you can append  to the front and  to the end and then do this:

```
private void ParseXML()
{           
    string xml = "<root><NAME>Robert</NAME> <TYPE>Type 2</TYPE><ADDRESS>Address 1</ADDRESS><ADDRESS>Address 2</ADDRESS><CITY>City For Address 1</CITY><CITY>City For Address 2</CITY><ZIP>Zip For City 1</ZIP><ZIP>ZIP For City 2</ZIP></root>";
    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    int count = xDoc.Descendants("ADDRESS").Count();
    var addressDict = new Dictionary<XElement, Dictionary<XElement, XElement>>();
    int skipIndex = 0;
    for (int takeIndex = 1; takeIndex <= count; takeIndex++)
    {
        var cityAndZIPDict = new Dictionary<XElement,XElement>();
        cityAndZIPDict.Add(xDoc.Descendants("CITY").Skip(skipIndex).Take(takeIndex).First(),xDoc.Descendants("ZIP").Skip(skipIndex).Take(takeIndex).First() );
        addressDict.Add(xDoc.Descendants("ADDRESS").Skip(skipIndex).Take(takeIndex).First(), cityAndZIPDict);
        skipIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Cut down my loops in half.